# Can anyone decipher what this snippet of assembly code is doing?

Tags: assembly, x86

There's two parts to my question.

The first mystery for me here is the code at 410407. I have 3 different versions of this code patch and in each version, the code at 410407 is slightly different.

Version 1: 6B784268
Version 2: 65784268
Version 3: 69784268

Popping these three into a disassembler comes out with one readable result, one gibberish result, and one half okay one. Converting them into decimal doesn't seem to give me much information either. Am I missing something here?

The second part of the question is that I am not really sure what the program is doing with the this code. I guess I can understand it is moving it into EAX but what about the rest? (Please be gentle with your answer, I am a beginner)

```
ADD ESP,3C
MOV EAX,00410407
MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX]
MOV BYTE PTR DS:[ESI+48],EAX
MOV BYTE PTR DS:[ESI+47],1
POP EDI
POP ESI
RETN
```

Comment: `MOV BYTE PTR DS:[ESI+48],EAX` is inconsistent, it would make sense with `AL` or with `DWORD` but not with mixed sizes, what's up with that?

Comment: Indeed, the bytes in the first part of your question don't decode to sensible instructions (in either byte order).  They are ASCII letters, `kxBh, exBh, ixBh` etc, so is it possible this is really data?  Or that execution does not go where you think it does?  Or that the code is rewritten in some way before being executed? Malware often likes to have encrypted code that gets decrypted on the fly.

Comment: And the second code snippet indeed seems to be loading a dword from address 00410407 as data, then storing it somewhere else.  But not executing it.

Comment: Basically if the code at 00410407 is 69784268, you can only join online servers where the code is also 69784268. If your code says 6B78468 then it'll say there is a mismatch. So I guess my question is really whether these numbers have any meaning on their own or whether you can replace them with basically anything you like.

Comment: Are those patched bytes maybe not the start of an instruction, instead just replacing some later bytes of the first instruction?  Without context, nobody can tell you what might be doing on.

Comment: Nope, the are put in the middle of a group of NOPs. The code immediately before 00410407 is a RETN instruction. When the patch isn't applied, the entire strip of code is 
`ADD ESP,3C
POP EDI
POP ESP`
So I am wondering if the code is just simply a way of the patch identifying itself. And it's written with the hex 69, 6B etc. because those numbers won't try to execute anything into memory when the CPU sees it.